# How to get the value of a key, value pair in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've got a list of dictionaries with key, value pairs. I am trying to create a function that retrieves the value when a specific key is given. I've done the following but I'm not getting any further.

```
my_list = [
     {'name': 'address', 'value': 'Testraat 100'},
     {'name': 'ripeID', 'value': 'nan'},
     {'name': 'name', 'value': 'Admin Account'},
     {'name': 'phone', 'value': '+31 6 12345678'},
     {'name': 'email', 'value': 'admin@domein.nl'}
]

def get_value(lst, key):
    for d in lst:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if v == key:
                print(v)

address = get_value(my_list, 'address')

# prints: address
# desired answer: Teststraat 100
```

Comment: Just a comment (does not address the question) but I can't help wondering if your data structure makes sense. Sure it works but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor tweaks will do:

```
def get_value(lst, key):
    for d in lst:
        if d["name"] == key:  # you know which key you are looking for
             return d["value"]  # return the value of that dict

address = get_value(my_list, 'address')
address
# 'Testraat 100'
```

There is a more concise way of writing this pattern in python, using `next` with a generator:

```
def get_value(lst, key):
    return next(d["value"] for d in lst if d["name"] == key)
```

Unlike the first approach which returns `None` when the key is not found, this will raise an error. You can provide a default to `next` to achieve the identical behaviour:

```
def get_value(lst, key):
    return next((d["value"] for d in lst if d["name"] == key), None)
```

Comment: The last one seems to be the most clean and safe one. Great use of the next() function. Thanks a lot, I've accepted your answer :-)

Comment: If you have an element which value is None, you won't be able to detect if the value was None or if the key was absent of the parsed dictionnary. I think that I gave a more complete solution below depending on the use. I like the use of generator in your answers tho.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
def get_value(lst, key):
  return [d["value"] for d in lst if d["name"] == key]
        
get_value(my_list, 'address')

#output
['Testraat 100']
```

If you want name as well:

```
def get_value(lst, key):
  return [(d["name"], d["value"]) for d in lst if d["name"] == key]

get_value(my_list, 'address')

#output
[('address', 'Testraat 100')]
```

Comment: a) This returns a (possibly singleton or empty) list of dicts, not the value the OP is looking for.
b) Even if you were to pick the value from the first dict in your return list, the list comprehension does not short-circuit (stop when the key is found) but will do spurious iterations.

Comment: a) second part is an option if they want both the values of keys `name` and `value`.         
b) OP did not mention if there are repeating values or not to stop iterations. I consider there are only unique values since they did not mention.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done quite the same as the above suggested answers, but with increased control in case you dictionnary does not always specify a key `value` or `name`.

You can try this code:

```py
my_list = [
{'name': 'address', 'value': None},
{'name': 'ripeID', 'value': 'nan'},
{'name': 'name', 'value': 'Admin Account'},
{'name': 'phone', 'value': '+31 6 12345678'},
{'name': 'email', 'value': 'admin@domein.nl'}
]

def get_value(lst, key):
   return [e["value"] for e in lst if e.get("name") == key and "value" in e]

get_value(my_list, "address")
>>> [None]

get_value(my_list, "absent_key")
>>> []

get_value(my_list, "name")
>>> ["Admin Account"]
```